# SaveFileDialog surprisingly adds extension to file

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

When I select file name "image.mgm", dialog System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog **surprisingly** adds extension .BMP and return "**image.mgm.BMP**" via property FileName.
It doesn't happen for "image.png".

Several samples:

- image.bmp ==> image.bmp
- image.png ==> image.png
- image.mgm ==> **image.mgm.BMP**
- image.MGM ==> image.MGM

How can I fix the unexpected (for me) behavior?

Source of sample can be found on github: https://github.com/constructor-igor/TechSugar/tree/master/WinForm/FileSaveDialogIssue/FileSaveDialogIssue

**UPD**: 
*additional fact: when I add key "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.mgm" to registry, "file dialog" stop's to add ".BMP" to .mgm*

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.saveFileDialog.AddExtension = false;
    }

    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog.Title = @"Save calculated image";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = "noname.tiff";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = @"My Files(*.BMP;*.MGM;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.MGM;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("File name {0}", saveFileDialog.FileName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you select the "All files" filter in the dialog? If not: try it before pressing the save button.

Comment: no problem with "All files" filter, but I don't understand what a problem with "My Files" filter.

Comment: Oh... I didn't realize that .mgm was part of the "My Files" filter. Are you sure that "bmp" and "png" (lower case) works?

Comment: yes: I tested several times.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use non-capital letters when defining file mask

```
saveFileDialog.Filter = @"My Files(*.BMP;*.MGM;*.PNG)|*.bmp;*.mgm;*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
```

This will work with either "1.mgm" or "1.MGM"

---

However, "1.mGm" and "1.MgM" won't work, could be fixed by adding "*.mGm" mask (just this one fixes both cases).

But then you still have problem with "1.Mgm".. sigh.

```
"*.mgm;*.mGm;*.Mgm;*.mgM;"
```

Comment: ok, I agree, it's possible to implement different work a rounds, but I want to understand the issue. Seems, dialog adds first extension from filter for unknown extensions. When I select "1.exe" it doesn't add ".BMP", but when I select "1.exec" it adds

Comment: I am also curious what is wrong and why it still adds extensions disregards explicitly specified `AddExtension = false`.

Comment: The [setting property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog.cs,bd498fa26976958b) and [checking its value](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog.cs,7aeec959d11b6f08) seems ok to me, it shouldn't add **anything** to file name.

Comment: additional fact: when I add key "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mgm" to registry, "file dialog" stop's to add ".BMP"